# Help with Probability distributions arithmetics

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Why is $\sqrt{2}X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,2)$ if $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$?

Is this kind of calculations applicable to all probability distributions?

Comment: It is applicable when you are dealing with a scaling parameter. Here the standard deviation $\sigma$ is the scaling parameter. You also have the mean as the location parameter. In general, you have a family of distributions created by location-scale transformation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to show this is to use a change of variable. 
Call $Y = \sqrt 2 X$. Then $X =  Y/\sqrt 2$, and
\begin{align*}f_Y(y) &= \frac{f_X(y/\sqrt 2)}{\left|\frac{dy}{dx}\right|_{y/\sqrt 2}} \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{y/\sqrt 2 -0}{1}\right)^2\right\}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sqrt 2} \exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{y -0}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2\right\}.
\end{align*}
This is the density for a $N(0, 2)$. In general, this is not applicable to all distributions. You will have to become familiar with each one.